# Gatsby build fails because of es6 use in node_modlues with UglifyJs

Tags: ecmascript-6, node-modules, uglifyjs, gatsby

My static website built using Gatsby utilizes a number of node_modules that use es6. From what I understand, I am facing the issue that is talked about in this link `https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/3780` where my gatsby build fails because uglify is not able to handle es6, and the babel presets built into gatsby do not transpile the node_modules. My initial thought was to edit the babel presets to include the node_modules, but I got a bunch of new errors on gatsby build that looked like this `Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset`. What other solutions can I try?

Answer (score 0):

After trying a number of different solutions, I ended up copying the offending node packages locally and requiring the local versions instead of the node_modules version. This way I could transpile them myself to es5. This is a temporary solution until my team can move to using Gatsby 2 which will fix this problem in the future.